# Pandas fill multiple columns with 0 when null

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, I can fill a single column with 0 as follows:

```
df['COL'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

is it possible to fill multiple columns in same step?

Comment: `df.fillna(0)` ?

Comment: No, not all columns, only a selected list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess:

```
df[list_cols] = df[list_cols].fillna(0)
```

Comment: is this better than the inplace=True option?

Comment: No, `inplace` won't work for multi-columns. I'm not sure why, might be related to slicing.